# Is it possible to implement custom destructuring for non data class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin data classes can be destructured like so:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val thing = Stuff(1, "Hi", true)
    val(thing1, thing2, thing3) = thing

    println(thing1)
}

data class Stuff(val thing1: Int, val thing2: String, val thing3: Boolean)
```

I could be misreading the docs, or maybe I just couldn't find an example, but I'm looking for a way to implement custom destructuring of non-data classes. Is this possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to make this work like this:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val person = Person("first", "last")
    val(param1, param2) = person
    println(param1)
    println(param2)
}

class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    operator fun component1() = firstName
    operator fun component2() = lastName
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[Destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) is performed by calling functions `component1`, `component2`, `component3` etc, on the instance being destructured.

These functions can be either member functions declared inside your class or extension functions. Also component functions must have `operator` keyword to indicate they are to satisfy a convention, namely destructuring one.

For data classes compiler generates corresponding component function for each property of data class declared in its primary constructor.

An example of class with custom component functions:

```
class Result(val e: Exception?) {
    val hasFailed = e != null

    operator fun component1(): Exception? = e
    operator fun component2(): Boolean = hasFailed
}

val (e, hasFailed) = Result(RuntimeException())
```